# Outlook forcing me to original email account settings

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail-imap

I have several email accounts on my Outlook (Work email, personal, my son's football club im the admin of).

I have moved the football email account from a Google Workspace email to another provider.  This works if I send an email to the address then it appears in the new provider's webmail client so I'm confident the DNS is correct.

The trouble is that I deleted the Gmail account from outlook thinking that I could then read it with the new server settings but it just always adds the Gmail one (i don't even have to type the password).

I have gone back and checked stuff like autodiscover settings thinking it might be that.  Also tried removing, closing outlook, restarting the computer and then putting the detials in thinking maybe a chache might be cleared.  Have also tried to PC's (admittedly both are Win11 running outlook and both had this account originally so probably the same issue anyway

Cheers

Comment: If you create a new Outlook profile, load that profile, what happens?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions in the "Create a new profile" section of the following article, then add the account into the new Outlook profile to check the result.

[Overview of Outlook e-mail profiles](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/overview-of-outlook-e-mail-profiles-9073a8ac-c3d6-421d-b5b9-fcedff7642fc)

In case the issue persists, do you mind telling us what is the "another provider" so that maybe we can try searching further for similar cases.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks both for your suggestions.  I tried to add the profile and I even tried removing all profiles / restarting the machine and adding in from scratch but it never seemed to help.

I have actually figured it out though.  So what made things confusing was that the domain was bought through Godaddy, it then directed to a site built in Wix.  It seems that Wix was actually what I set the google workplaces account up with.  Somehow even though the MX records were pointing to my new provider (ukdomainnameregistrations).

So to fix it I went into to Google workplaces thinking I would remove the account however that pushed me back to Wix as they were the reseller.  In there i cancelled the subscription thinking it would cancel Google but it only did the billing.

I therefore went back to google and created a new primary domain with an old dormant domain and fake email.  I was then able to switch the wix stuff to this domain and then delete the original domain stuff.

I assume at this point a hidden DNS record somewhere was deleted as although when starting the outlook add account process it would suggest the email address and use the google settings this process would fail and ask for new server info which then allowed me to enter the new details and voila - all worked.

Something of a song a dance but I guess thats my fault for using different providers for each step!

Comment: Convoluted story. But anyways, great to know that you've managed to sort things out and thanks for the share!